# wx script can't see numpy, but it's installed

Tags: numpy, wxpython

I had a wx script working on winxp (at work). it was upgraded to win7_64. I installed python2 and wxpython (both 32bit). now my script doesn't want to run. it says "ImportError: NumPy not found.". so I installed numpy from numpy.org, but it didnt change anything. I can import wx, I can import numpy, but when I try to run my wx script, it says that numpy is not installed. I removed and reinstalled everything but nothing changed.
what to do?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the way you installed numpy?

Comment: I downloaded numpy-1.9.2-win32-superpack-python2.7.exe from numpy.org and installed it. installer saw my python 27 installation folder

Comment: Sorry, I do not know much about the exe installer, but in my experience the wheels installer that you can find with this [link](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) should work best under windows.

Comment: ok, so I uninstalled prev numpy and installed whl from your link, but nothing changed. but I also noticed it's not a problem of wx only, because other wx scrpits works fine. this particular that doesn't want to work also uses wx.lib.plot module - maybe here is a source of a problem. but I still don't know how to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably your `numpy` is too "new" or your `wxPython` is too old.
For example the combination wxPython < 3.0 and numpy > 1.9 will not work for the plot module (2.9.5 + numpy 1.8.0 and 3.0.2 + numpy 1.9.2 **do** actually work).

Reason should be file `<site-packages.wx>/lib/plot.py` (2.9.5):

```
# Needs NumPy
try:
    import numpy.oldnumeric as _Numeric
except:
    msg= """
    This module requires the NumPy module, which could not be
    imported.  It probably is not installed (it's not part of the
    standard Python distribution). See the Numeric Python site
    (http://numpy.scipy.org) for information on downloading source or
    binaries."""
    raise ImportError, "NumPy not found.\n" + msg
```

and as used in 3.0.2):

```
# Needs NumPy
try:
    import numpy as np
except:
```

`numpy.oldnumeric` is no longer part of numpy 1.9.2, `wx.lib.plot` was developed for ancient array libraries and you can clearly see its age.

Comment: you are right. that was it. i installed newest wx and numpy 1.8.1 and now everything works. thanks.